Winged Humans: Tail or No Tail?
Ignoring the numerous problems with how a human would fly, would a winged human fly better with a tail?
First style - Human, bird wings, no tail.
Second - Same as first, but with a bird tail  (artstation.com/artwork/yJbrwn)(reference)
Third - Hard to describe. I couldn't find any pictures, but imagine those artists depictions of feathered dinosaurs, specifically the ones that look like Velociraptors, and look at the tail. Then imagine the tail, but on a person with bird wings.
(Sorry if this is confusing and vague)
Which of the above three works the best for flight?

If the question is purely from an aeronautical point of view - then having a Tail that can be used as an aerodynamic surface adds so many benefits:
Directional stability and agility being the main two.
Directional stability because as a smaller control surface, you can use it to fine-tune when gliding or cruising, rather than using the larger wing/chest/back muscles.
Agility because you get to do things like stalling one wing and vectoring the airflow on your rear.

but it also adds a lot of weight and drag, which is why flying aniamlas make the tail sshorter and shorter.

It depends on how long ago they developed flight. In real evolution all three groups of vertibrate fliers (birds, bats, pterosaurs) started with long tails with flight control surfaces in early diversification and as the evolved to be more specialized in flight and for better and better control in flight the tail gets smaller and smaller. The thought is that the tail is helping with maneuverabilty but the weight and drag are a big enough disadvantage they get rid of it once they can make up for it in other ways.
It also depends on what kind of flier they are tails help mostly with low speed maneuverabilty but not much for long distance flight. so are the people distance fliers or precision fliers.
But really the human shape is so poorly suited to flight it really doesn't matter.
early pterosaurs

later pterosaurs

Birds


Humans have very long, and very heavy legs. Any gain in lift or maneuverability from the tail would be more than negated by the  legs dangling down under it.
Solution: give your flying humans thin, lightweight legs covered in feathers. I would imagine a strip of long, stiff feathers going down the outside surface of each leg, culminating in a triangular feathery "fin" on the calf, with possibly a smaller feather fin o the back of the ankle to serve as a stabilizer. So essentially, its option 3, but the tail is legs held together.
This is the only way to have a flyign human with even remotely humanlike legs.
Of course, the other problem is that it would be next to impossible for winged humans to actually achieve lift, but this is beside the point here. On average, a human would need at least a 7 meter wingspan to fly at all, and they would be really only able to lift if they jumped off a cliff first. A wide, feather leg-tail is a must then, they need all the surface area they can get.
